# How to fix Symfony2 SonataAdminBundle undefined index _per_page ?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1, sonata-admin

I just upgraded my symfony2.1.6 to Symfony2.1.7 and bumped in to this issue. Please let me know I can provide more details. It was fine with 2.1.6 but does not seem to work in 2.1.7.

This error comes when I try to access Customer.php Entity (customer listing)

```
Notice: Undefined index: _per_page in /var/www/playground/vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Sonata/AdminBundle/Admin/Admin.php line 720
```

Comment: Well the quick way would probably be to supply a `per_page` argument in your listBuilder, but thats really a workaround. I ahvent come across this yet myself and am using sonata on a current project. I might still be on 2.1.6 though... ill have to look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks prodigitalson for comment, I solved the issue as you suggested by passing the argument.

Now my CustomerAdmin.php extends AbstractAdmin class which is overriding the Admin
This AbstractAdmin contains common code and all other Admin classes extends this Abstract Class.

```
<?php

namespace xxxx\AdminBundle\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;

abstract class AbstractAdmin extends Admin
{
    /** @var int */
    protected $maxPerPage = 10;
    //other attributes

    public function __construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName)
    {
        parent::__construct($code, $class, $baseControllerName);
        $this->fields = $this->sortFields($fields);

        // custome arguments
        if (!$this->hasRequest()) {
            $this->datagridValues = array(
              ***'_per_page' => $this->maxPerPage*** //passing ***_per_page*** argument
        );
    }
}


<?php

namespace xxxx\AdminBundle\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;

class CustomerAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
   //code here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The datagridValues are initialized on the $datagridValues of the base Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin class. The reason i saw this problem was when people where updating $this->datagridValues in their code by assigning a full array. We fixed the issue by assigning single values in the array instead of overwriting the full array.